# Capistrano 3 at deployment on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, git, capistrano, tar

I try to deploy rails app with Capistrano v3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS...

but Capistrano at deployment gives an error "buffer overflow detected : git terminated".

Buffer size = 1024 mb.

git archive = ~80mb

what could be the reason?

Help please.

log:

```
    Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -C /var/www/releases/20140321121112 on localhost
DEBUG [994e90ef] Command: cd /var/www/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/home/que/tmp/SP1/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -C /var/www/releases/20140321121112 )
DEBUG [994e90ef]        *** buffer overflow detected ***: git terminated
DEBUG [994e90ef]        ======= Backtrace: =========
DEBUG [994e90ef]        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7ff55f50cf47]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x109e40)[0x7ff55f50be40]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x1092a9)[0x7ff55f50b2a9]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_default_xsputn+0xdd)[0x7ff55f47e13d]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_vfprintf+0x1d42)[0x7ff55f44c702]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__vsprintf_chk+0x94)[0x7ff55f50b344]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__sprintf_chk+0x7d)[0x7ff55f50b28d]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x46d4d4]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x46be16]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x4dcdd2]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x4dcee9]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x4dd020]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x46c32b]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x46d7f5]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x46cec1]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x40e915]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x405634]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x404a30]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ff55f42376d]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        git[0x404e65]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        ======= Memory map: ========
DEBUG [994e90ef]        00400000-00541000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 42184                              /usr/bin/git
DEBUG [994e90ef]        00741000-00742000 r--p 00141000 08:01 42184                              /usr/bin/git
DEBUG [994e90ef]        00742000-00749000 rw-p 00142000 08:01 42184                              /usr/bin/git
DEBUG [994e90ef]        00749000-00799000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
DEBUG [994e90ef]        022c2000-02f39000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55a3fe000-7ff55a413000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 764                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55a413000-7ff55a612000 ---p 00015000 08:01 764                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55a612000-7ff55a613000 r--p 00014000 08:01 764                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55a613000-7ff55a614000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 764                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55a614000-7ff55f148000 r--p 00000000 08:01 407827                     /var/www/repo/objects/pack/pack-30eaca3043a16789d9258a0665d5945efc6e36d7.pack
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f148000-7ff55f402000 r--p 00000000 08:01 8825
DEBUG [994e90ef]                       /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f402000-7ff55f5b7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 21414                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f5b7000-7ff55f7b7000 ---p 001b5000 08:01 21414                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f7b7000-7ff55f7bb000 r--p 001b5000 08:01 21414                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f7bb000-7ff55f7bd000 rw-p 001b9000 08:01 21414                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f7bd000-7ff55f7c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f7c2000-7ff55f7da000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 21423                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f7da000-7ff55f9d9000 ---p 00018000 08:01 21423                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f9d9000-7ff55f9da000 r--p 00017000 08:01 21423                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f9da000-7ff55f9db000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 21423                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f9db000-7ff55f9df000 rw-p 00000000 0
DEBUG [994e90ef]        0:00 0
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f9df000-7ff55f9f7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 21419                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55f9f7000-7ff55fbf7000 ---p 00018000 08:01 21419                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55fbf7000-7ff55fbf8000 r--p 00018000 08:01 21419                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55fbf8000-7ff55fbf9000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 21419                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55fbf9000-7ff55fbfb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55fbfb000-7ff55fc11000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4881                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55fc11000-7ff55fe10000 ---p 00016000 08:01 4881                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55fe10000-7ff55fe11000 r--p 00015000 08:01 4881                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55fe11000-7ff55fe12000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 4881                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55fe12000-7ff55fe34000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 21426
DEBUG [994e90ef]          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff55fff1000-7ff560023000 r--p 00000000 08:01 407828                     /var/www/repo/objects/pack/pack-30eaca3043a16789d9258a0665d5945efc6e36d7.idx
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff560023000-7ff560027000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff560031000-7ff560034000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff560034000-7ff560035000 r--p 00022000 08:01 21426                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7ff560035000-7ff560037000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 21426                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7fffb7979000-7fffb799a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        7fffb79fe000-7fffb7a00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        tar:
DEBUG [994e90ef]        Unexpected EOF in archive
DEBUG [994e90ef]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        tar:
DEBUG [994e90ef]        Unexpected EOF in archive
DEBUG [994e90ef]
DEBUG [994e90ef]        tar:
DEBUG [994e90ef]        Error is not recoverable: exiting now

cap aborted!
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Nothing written
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:142:in `block (4 levels) in _execute'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:164:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:166:in `block in _execute'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `tap'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `_execute'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/git.rb:11:in `git'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/git.rb:33:in `release'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:65:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:81:in `within'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:63:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:89:in `with'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/que/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:create_release
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Command::Failed: git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Nothing written
```

Comment: Can you try checking out from that git repository manually? Seems like this is git only error, with Capistrano having nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my 12.04 was installed git version 1.7.9.5

After update git (git-core) to version 1.9.1 the problem was resolved!